# Web scraping with vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm looking forward to make a web-scraping app with Vue js.

What are the packages should I get for this project ??

Looking around in web I get the following:

1. `cheerio`
2. `node-fetch`
3. `axios`
4. `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`

Is there anything more I should get to get-started   or any better options for above mentioned packages ?

Comment: Vue.js isn’t really going to be suitable for this. It’s a JavaScript framework for adding component-based interactivity to a web page; not for long-running utilities like web scrapers.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better option suited for this would be [Pupeteer](https://pptr.dev/). You can setup some cloud functions with Firebase that return Promises with the fetched data. This has to be done as Pupeteer is server side only.

Pupeteer fetching looks like this:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

I would keep all the web scraping on the server and not on client side as it can reduce speed.

Comment: Pupeteer is the way to go if you need to get stuff of the internet

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do the web-scraping on the client-side, then use `cheerio`. You also need to find a way to do a CORS request from the client side.

If you want to do the web-scraping on the server-side, use `cheerio` or `pupeteer`, `cheerio` is enough for most use case, but if you are doing some advance scraping, sometimes `cheerio` isn't enough, so you need to use `pupeteer` since `pupeteer` is a headless browser, unlike `cheerio` which is just a *parser*. Use `cheerio` if it's possible, since its more lightweight than `pupeteer`.